# Right click flash app on mac with firefox triggers mousedown

Tags: javascript, actionscript-3, apache-flex, firefox

I have an issue that only happens when I run my app on FireFox on a mac, when user hits the right click, a mouseDown event is dispatched which causes unwanted behaviour.

Did anyone ever encountered this issue? any way around it ?

thanks

Comment: You should make an [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and clarify if the mousedown event is a JavaScript event (as your tags suggest) or an ActionScript event.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I solved this issue by using RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN and RIGHT_MOUSE_UP events. See my code. If right mouse is DOWN, left mouse DOWN will not be processing. After right mouse is UP, left mouse DOWN will be processing. So, now after clicking the right mouse button MOUSE_DOWN will not be dispatched. Sorry for my English.

```
package
{
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;

    public class Main extends Sprite
    {
        private var isRightDown:Boolean;

        public function Main()
        {
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_DOWN, rightDown);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.RIGHT_MOUSE_UP, rightUp);
            stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_DOWN, leftDown);
        }

        private function leftDown(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            if (!isRightDown)
            {
                trace("left DOWN");
            }
        }

        private function rightUp(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            isRightDown = false;
            trace("right UP");
        }

        private function rightDown(event:MouseEvent):void
        {
            isRightDown = true;
            trace("right DOWN");
        }
    }
}
```